# What holds strong reference onto my viewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, strong-references

I am removing viewController from controller hierarchy with `removeFromParentViewController`, but `deinit` of view controller not get called. How can I check what holds strong reference on it?

Any way to see reference graph exist in memory?

This is how my swap` method looks like:

```
public class func swap(fromViewController: UIViewController!, toViewController: UIViewController!, containerViewController: UIViewController!) {

    fromViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    containerViewController.addChildViewController(toViewController)
    toViewController.view.frame = containerViewController.view.bounds

    containerViewController.transitionFromViewController(fromViewController, toViewController: toViewController, duration: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {}, completion: {finished in
        fromViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
        toViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(containerViewController)
    })
}
```

In `transitionFromViewController` `completion` should I add / remove destination / source views?

Any way to access `refCount` of a `viewController` in Swift?

---

I tried to analyse code with `Instruments`. Figure out what hold strong reference to view controller, but couldn't figure out. Any help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: in Swift `dealloc` is called `deinit`, and I guess I forget to remove the view?!

Comment: Could you use viewWillDisappear to achieve your goals?

Comment: @bteapot `func transitionFromViewController(, toViewController:, duration:, options:, animations:, completion:)` handles the views.

Comment: @Tim finally I used `viewWillDisappear` approach to remove strong references from array and so viewController get `deinit`ed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use profile the code with Instruments. In Xcode, select Product > Profile. When Instruments loads, select Allocations as the template.

This will allow you to trace which objects are setting what strong references.

Comment: I tried figure out what holds reference to my `MovieTableViewController` but hard to say. Any suggestion? I have edited the question.

Comment: @János First, I would look for strong delegates, and blocks for retain cycles. The profile tool should point these cycles out to you.